# Controlar acesso em duas URLs com o .htaccess

Tags: php, htaccess, url-amigavel

Eu tenho a pasta de *login* do meu site `www.meusite.com.br/login` e que. após logar. vai para o `www.meusite.com.br/painel`. A questão é que preciso aplicar uma regra para o *login* e outra regra para o painel, porém uma subscreve a outra:

```
RewriteEngine On
Options All -Indexes
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ login.php?lg=$1
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ painel.php?url=$1
```

Comment: Você explicitamente disse ao seu servidor: "redirecione todas as URL para `login.php` e redirecione todas as URL para `painel.php`". Quais exatamente seriam as regras de redirecionamento para cada?

Comment: então...eu tenho uma pasta admin com  login.php e painel.php;
exmplo: https://www.aluguetemporada.com.br/auth/habr/login
ai depois https://www.aluguetemporada.com.br/auth/painel

Comment: na login tenho arquivos css...e no painel tenho toda a estrutura, ou seja, preciso que sejam isolados;

Comment: o arquivo htaccess ta dentro da pasta admin